In Python, I want a list (or something) to pop its last member when I return from a function
This works, but is it the best way? Performance is not a concern. It just seems clunky and error-prone to do the pop manually.
I want to access all parts of the list in the called functions, but I don't want to know about them from the caller.
def outer():
    myList = ['outer']
    middle(myList)
    print("back to outer:", myList)
    
def middle(theList):
    theList.append('middle')
    inner(theList)
    print("back to middle:", theList)
    theList.pop()

def inner(expandedList):
    expandedList.append('inner')
    print("inner:", expandedList)
    expandedList.pop()
    
outer()


>>>
inner: ['outer', 'middle', 'inner']
back to middle: ['outer', 'middle']
back to outer: ['outer']
>>> 

If it helps to give context, I'm writing an XML to STL application. As I walk in, x/y/z positional shifts are cumulative as they are written out as absolute triangulated facet vertices, but when I return from a nested situation (the <container> element in my DTD), I no longer should incorporate the shift/offset of the inner element(s).
I've been programming since the 80s, but am relatively new to Python. Variable scope has been one of the more difficult aspects for me to come to terms with. I initially thought the meaning of the list would just naturally pop.
Editing my question to say @Guy has given a good answer.
Beyond that, if it's not going too far afield, I'd like to consider this alternate code sample:
def outer():
    myList = ['outer']
    myVal = 7
    print("outer myVal", myVal)
    middle(myList, myVal)
    print("back to outer:", myList)
    print("back to outer:", myVal)
    
def middle(theList, theVal):
    theList.append('middle')
    theVal += 4
    print("middle theVal", theVal)
    inner(theList, theVal)
    print("back to middle:", theList)
    print("back to middle:", theVal)
    #theList.pop()

def inner(expandedList, fiddledVal):
    expandedList.append('inner')
    fiddledVal = 47
    print("inner expandedList:", expandedList)
    print("inner fiddledVal:", fiddledVal)
    #expandedList.pop()
    
outer()

>>>
outer myVal 7
middle theVal 11
inner expandedList: ['outer', 'middle', 'inner']
inner fiddledVal: 47
back to middle: ['outer', 'middle', 'inner']
back to middle: 11
back to outer: ['outer', 'middle', 'inner']
back to outer: 7
>>> 

Simple integers, after returning from a called function, have the same values they had before their visit to the called function. Lists are modified by the called function in ways that persist after returning from it.
Short of reading all the Python documentation, is there something I could read to better understand the underlying distinction between the integer and the list?

Quite unclear. Please make sure your [mre] actually highlights your problem, explaining clearly what's wrong with your outcomes and what you expect instead...

I understand the function. I couldn't understand why this? is not sufficient like: myList = ['outer', 'middle', 'inner']; print(f'inner: {myList}'); print(f'back to middle:{myList[:2]});   print(f'back to outer: myList[:1]')

I'm afraid I find the first of these comments itself quite unclear. My problem is not knowing the best way to code something, as I explained -- how would I highlight the "not knowing" aspect?
As for trimming the tail of the list in the caller function, that really seems like a poor design pattern. The calling function shouldn't assume that the called function added one and only one item to the list. Better that the called function should have to remember to clean up after itself than that approach.

"Short of reading all the Python documentation, is there something I could read to better understand the underlying distinction between the integer and the list?" you never mutate any int object. Indeed, int objects don't expose any mutator methods, so they are considered "immutable". But the objects are being treated the same way. Assignment to a variable never mutates, so if you did theList = theList + ["middle"] you'd see the same behavior (where you create a new list object using the + operator, instead of using a mutator method like .append)

you should really read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

There are more options, like working with local lists in the functions, but IMO the cleanest way is to just send a copy of the list to the next function
def outer():
    lst = ['outer']
    middle(lst[:])
    print("back to outer:", lst)


def middle(lst):
    lst.append('middle')
    inner(lst[:])
    print("back to middle:", lst)


def inner(lst):
    lst.append('inner')
    print("inner:", lst[:])


Passing a copy makes sense. Each function can pass an augmented (appended-to) copy of the list to functions it calls.

How do I accept this as my answer? I plan to implement this in my code tomorrow.
I'd still like to know what data types, if any, are scoped within a called function. But that is not the question I asked. This does answer my question, and it does represent a clear improvement over what I was experimenting with.

@Tamias You can click the check mark on the left of the answer.
There is a lot of reading material about scopes, like this, but I think you want to know more about mutable and immutable

@Tamias data types don't have scope. Variables do, variables are simply names that refer to objects in a namespace

@Tamias note, alternatively, the function should make the copy, this also makes it so the function doesn't mutate its input, which is considered an antipattern. For example, in middle, you could just do lst = lst.copy() at the beginning.

Just showing how I incorporated feedback from @Guy and @juanpa into my test script. I appreciate the help and explanations about "mutability".
def outer():
    myList = ['outer']
    middle(myList)
    print("back to outer:", myList)
    
def middle(lst):
    theList = lst.copy()
    theList.append('middle')
    inner(theList)
    print("back to middle:", theList)

def inner(lst):
    expandedList = lst.copy()
    expandedList.append('inner')
    print("inner expandedList:", expandedList)
    
outer()


>>>
inner expandedList: ['outer', 'middle', 'inner']
back to middle: ['outer', 'middle']
back to outer: ['outer']
>>> 

I did also find https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html suggested by @juanpa quite helpful. It took me a few days to find time to read it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
